# How to build a blog without a database

Tags: php, blogs

I have PHP hosting on a website, i am not really a computer guy, but i wanted to build a website with a blog, i do not have a database host account.

Thanks!

Comment: As you have said you are not a computer guy, if you just want to blog, might it not be easier to simply sign up for a blogspot/blogger account from Google (or many other free blogger sites)? http://www.blogger.com

Comment: Well i t would be easier, but i want to learn how to program this myself.

Comment: if you want to learn, then get a site that has a db. (your home computer is fine) you will learn little of real use with out a db, as there is no site that does not use one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but take a look at your phpinfo() too and see if it has drivers installed for SQLite. You don't need a database account to use a SQLite database, because it's a single file you can store somewhere on your host.

Comment: That sounds pretty good, will this work with FireFTP?

Comment: Yeah, you can use any ftp program to get it onto your host. Have you looked at using a package like XAMPP (win) MAMP(mac)? That way you can develop the whole thing on your own computer without the need to upload everything all the time.

Comment: I was not familiar with that, I have a mac.  MAMP, this will make my mac be the server correct?

Comment: // edit. Read your comment wrong. Yes, it will create an apache / php installation on your own computer, so you can test your scripts on /localhost/ instead of your webserver. imagine uploading everything every time you edit your script. Would be a handfull... I use MAMP myself. It's just a single program with an easy interface. [link](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

Comment: I see, that is cleaver. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of [Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/) which generates your site from php templates and text files. You could also use a free service such as tumblr or wordpress.com with a custom url.

Comment: Hi dave, Thanks, i am more interested in learning some web programming logic in lieu of using a service, or possibly just use html

Comment: In that case, I would highly recommend Stacey. There are some prebuilt templates that you could modify, or you can build your own from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at a tempting system like [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or it's bigger daddy, [handlebars.js](http://handlebars.strobeapp.com/).  The templates look like regular HTML, with embedded handlebars expressions.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would also **highly** recommend Stacey, or it's [multitude of forks](https://github.com/search?q=stacey&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1), especially [Stacey's Mom](https://github.com/madaemo/staceys-mom).  It uses Markdown, and [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) to amazing effect.  It is a really nice way of organizing content with flat files, and lets you get closer to the code generation than most CMS's warrant or permit.  Check out [Assemblage r3
A template for the Stacey CMS](http://www.yconst.com/web/assemblage/) which is REALLY nice and integrates the amazingly talented [David Desandro's](http://desandro.com/) *isotope* [layout engine](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)..

[image: r3 Assemblage theme running on Stacey CMS]

With Stacey's mom, there is only ONE PAGE, and you still get all the features of a real CMS with no database hassle, the ability to change everything in plain text, and your ENTIRE code looks like this, lol...

```
:head
<title>@name's Portfolio </title>
:javascriptandcss
<body>
<div id="container">
:navigation
<h1 class="col six">
<a href="@root_path">@title</a>
<strong>@tagline</strong>
<div id="content" class="col eight">
:projects
<hr>
:skills
</div>
<div class="col four" id="side">
:about
:footer
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store your posts in html templates. This way, your blog will be very fast as well. If Ruby is an option, you may also want to take a look at [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)

Comment: when you say html templates, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: It could be plain html pages, or .tpl pages that are loaded with php. You either just create a 100% html blog, or you can add some php that will load your template files and echo their contents(which would be your posts).

Answer (score -1):

Most hosting packages contain some sort of database package.  Are you certain yours doesn't?  If you, in fact, do not have a database package of any sort, you can still build a blog using PHP and flat files.  Check out http://w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp for PHP file commands.  It's probably a good idea to write your blogs in XML, so, while on that site, look at the XML lessons and make sure to visit a tutorial on simplexml in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

GetSimple is a CMS that doesn't require a database.  I'm using it in a similar situation where I don't have a database account.

http://get-simple.info/wiki/installation:requirements

Answer (score -1):

This thread is pretty old, but whoever is interested, have a look at [github.com/peternerlich/StaticBlogSystem](https://github.com/peternerlich/StaticBlogSystem).

I have now done exactly that, but without even using sqlite, I just push new articles up as files and the system finds them.

Answer (score -3):

This can simply be done by using jquery, javaScript and php. But for beginners I would suggest using  javaScript for coding your database because its easier to understand. The downside to using a javaScript database is all your information is vunerable to hackers. When using this method the scripts are handled on the client side instead of the server. Your passwords and personal info will be available via source code. If your not going to collect highly protected info from your users you will be OK. For now lol. I'd suggest learning php myself. It has lots more security feautures for hashing private info. Good luck!